# How to type a Vue component with all of its props, emits and exposed functions?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, typescript-generics

If I have a number of components following this structure:

```js
// MyComponent_*.vue

<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps<{
  task: Task;
}>();

defineEmits<{
  (event: 'finishedEditing'): void;
}>();

function focus() {
  // do stuff
}

defineExpose({
  focus
});
</script>
```

And I want to use them as dynamic `<component>`, how would I type them, so that the props, emits and exposed are reflected in that type?

So far I've figured out that props can be passed as the first parameter to the `Component` type like so:

```js
import type { Component } from "vue";
import type Task from "@/types/Task";
import MyComponent_A from "MyComponent_A.vue";
import MyComponent_B from "MyComponent_B.vue";
import MyComponent_C from "MyComponent_C.vue";

type TMyComponent = Component<{ task: Task }>;

const components: TMyComponent[] = [
  MyComponent_A,
  MyComponent_B,
  MyComponent_C
];
```

Comment: Why do you need to make many components that work the same? If you need a generic component just set your type's rules on the prop type. Or else, if you need different component names, import the component with desired names or register it globally by unique names.

Comment: @Raeisi i have an entity with multiple fields that are available to be edited, but they all should be edited in different ways. For example: Price should have an according mask, Location should have an autocomplete api connected to the input, Files should have a file upload modal. 

So each property has its own component that edits it, but the way these components interact with the parent are all the same.

Comment: I see. If I were you, I would make a wrapper component to handle multiple types. But, look at the following link. It might be helpful. https://logaretm.com/blog/generic-type-components-with-composition-api/